# Add JSF forms and Beans dynamically

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is there a way to add forms dynamically to JSF page?

I'd like to implement a form list this:

https://ibin.co/3KFXVdyKgOcZ.jpg
(as I'm not allowed to post Images I do only post a link...)

- the amount of products and levels should not be limited
- a product can be added on different levels in the product tree.
- there can be constraint between different products (e.g. workplaces in room 100 can not have 24 inch monitors), so I have to have one Bean that knows all selected products to ensure constraints.

So my idea is to implement custom components for each product.
If the user clicks 'Add monitor' I add the component to the ui (how to do that?). As I understand all components must be available in die XHTML beforehand and could only be hidden/displayed using *"rendered"*. But that would limit the number of products that can be added.

In the bean I'd add an instance of the class handling the new product. Here I am not sure how to map the new ui component to the newly added class instance or more general: How to map a complex ui tree to the backing bean?

I've looked at several DynaForm alternatives, but till now I'm not sure, if DynaForm (or JSF in general) is the way to go...

Any hint is appreciated...
Frank

**UPDATE**

Here's the application where I'd like to create a new frontend.
https://filebin.net/0wg9gqvp61ph5pd0/example.jpg

It's a Struts2 application, and every selectable poduct is listed in the JSP and is shown when the "super"-product is selected. The user can select products and the edit the attributes inline without ever opening a new dialog.

For the new implementation I was wondering, if one could achieve the same without providing all components beforehand. Therefore, wenn a User selects a "super"-product, the custom components for all subproducts must be added to the page and each of them must be bound to the corresponding bean.

As far as I know the Framework Vaadin, it's possible there because one can bind model bean to the ui component and then add the component to the component tree.

I'd like to know if it's possible with JSF too, as I'd prefer JSF over vaadin.

Comment: Try to make your question more detailed and legible.

Comment: I think you have to take a step back and think about your model first (inheritance?) and how the ui should work in general. Sounds like you made objects way to specific and try to make your UI match that.

Comment: What I mean is that this ui would become unusable to if you add to many 'products'...or have to many accessories within one product. Just create a button 'Add Product' open a dialog, choose a product. And have another button 'Add accessory' that opens a dialog where you can add one. You can even have the 'Add accessory' inside the 'Add product' dialog as well'.

Comment: If I get it right, you'd suggest to use new dialogs to add/edit new products/accessories? I added another Image to show what I try to achieve.